# Smart Contract NFT how to add price by code to whole items in collection?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, erc721

Greeting,

Could you tell me how to add price for every item in collection hosted by OpenSea ?

So, I have working code, It created:

1.Collection name (from construct before deploy)

2.NFT symbol  (from construct before deploy)

3.URI to ipfs (from construct before deploy ex: ipfs://QmQtP8RNjvcVtKqcPwukgckWF74ojBjzahVzE3qCCnqv4f/

My smart contract example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
  using Strings for uint256;

  string public baseURI;
  string public baseExtension = ".json";
  uint256 public cost = 10000000000000000;
  uint256 public maxSupply = 10000;
  uint256 public maxMintAmount = 100;
  bool public paused = false;
  mapping(address => bool) public whitelisted;

  constructor(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol,
    string memory _initBaseURI
  ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
    setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
    mint(msg.sender, 5); // 5- for test
  }

  // internal
  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return baseURI;
  }

  // public
  function mint(address _to, uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
    uint256 supply = totalSupply();
    require(!paused);
    require(_mintAmount > 0);
    require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount);
    require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply);

    if (msg.sender != owner()) {
        if(whitelisted[msg.sender] != true) {
          require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount);
        }
    }

    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
      _safeMint(_to, supply + i);
    }
  }

  function walletOfOwner(address _owner)
    public
    view
    returns (uint256[] memory)
  {
    uint256 ownerTokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
    uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](ownerTokenCount);
    for (uint256 i; i < ownerTokenCount; i++) {
      tokenIds[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
    }
    return tokenIds;
  }

  function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
    public
    view
    virtual
    override
    returns (string memory)
  {
    require(
      _exists(tokenId),
      "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
    );

    string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
    return bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
        ? string(abi.encodePacked(currentBaseURI, tokenId.toString(), baseExtension))
        : "";
  }

  //only owner
  function setCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner {
    cost = _newCost;
  }

  function getCost() public view returns (uint256) {
    return cost;
  }

  function setmaxMintAmount(uint256 _newmaxMintAmount) public onlyOwner {
    maxMintAmount = _newmaxMintAmount;
  }

  function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) public onlyOwner {
    baseURI = _newBaseURI;
  }

  function setBaseExtension(string memory _newBaseExtension) public onlyOwner {
    baseExtension = _newBaseExtension;
  }

  function pause(bool _state) public onlyOwner {
    paused = _state;
  }
 
 function whitelistUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
    whitelisted[_user] = true;
  }
 
  function removeWhitelistUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
    whitelisted[_user] = false;
  }

  function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
      uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
      payable(msg.sender).transfer(balance);
  }
}
```

and my item json file example:

```
{
  "description": "Test Description",
  "external_url": "http://testurl.com",
  "image": "ipfs://QmSrkLg3UR5AUthhCZfrK9nrX3fxJJ4aCJK7B99rUkCa72/4.png",
  "name": "Test Name #4",
  "symbol": "TNFT",
  "collection": {
    "name": "TestNFT123_321",
    "family": ""
  },
  "date": 1643919095,
  "attributes": {
    "Story": "In Caffe",
    "Company": "Test Company",
    "Some": "thing else"
  }
}
```

On the OpenSea I have created collection name with items, but, with active price button.
What I made wrong?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this issue, so:

1. Listing items on OpenSea could be with API endpoints (see OpenSea docs, and [here](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/master/scripts/sell.js)).
2. OpenSea listing could be on mainnet or Rinkeby network only (as of today no Polygon, BSC ...)
3. There are a lot of clickers, which emulate add item, name, price on Polygon network.

Waiting for API V2 OpenSea =((